# How to see stock's symbol when using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

import pandas_datareader.data as web

from datetime import datetime

start_date = '2019-11-26'

end_date = str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

tickers = ['IBM', 'AAPL','GOOG']

df = pd.concat([web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start_date, end_date) for ticker in tickers]).reset_index()

with pd.option_context('display.max_columns', 999):
    print(df)
```

When I run my code, I can see only "Date         High          Low         Open        Close    Volume     Adj Close" values. 
What I want to see is the stocks' names before the Date!
Please, help me out...

Comment: yahoo gives data without stocks' names so you would have to add names before you concatenate data.

Answer (score 1):

It always gives data without stocks' names so you have to add names before you concatenate data.

```
tickers = ['IBM', 'AAPL','GOOG']

data = []
for ticker in tickers:
    df = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start_date, end_date)
    df['Name'] = ticker
    data.append(df)

df = pd.concat(data).reset_index()
```

Comment: Appreciate it !

Comment: BTW: I found that it can be used `web.DataReader(['IBM', 'AAPL','GOOG'], ...)` but it gives stocks' names in header and it is not so useful.